# Creating a silverlight border in codebehind?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, grid, code-behind

I have the following border in XAML:

```
<Border
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
    Grid.RowSpan="3"
    CornerRadius="1,1,1,1"
    Background="Red"
    BorderBrush="#333333"
    BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"
    x:Name="border"
    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Border.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform />
            <SkewTransform />
            <RotateTransform />
            <TranslateTransform />
        </TransformGroup>
    </Border.RenderTransform>
    <ContentPresenter
        x:Name="contentPresenter"
        Margin="10,0,10,0"
        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
</Border>
```

and I'm trying to create a similar border in code behind (C#). I can't get beyond `Border b = new Border()`, I'm not sure how I'm supposed to put the border inside the specific grid column or how to span it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var border = new Border();

Grid.SetColumn(border, 0);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(border, 3);
Grid.SetRowSpan(border, 3);

border.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(1);
border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
border.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xff, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33));
border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
border.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);

var transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
transformGroup.Children.Add(new ScaleTransform());
transformGroup.Children.Add(new SkewTransform());
transformGroup.Children.Add(new RotateTransform());
transformGroup.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform());
border.RenderTransform = transformGroup;
```

Let me know if you want me to set the rest of the properties.

Answer (score 2):

If that can help you :

```
            Border b = new Border();
            Grid.SetColumn(b, 0);
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(b, 3);
            Grid.SetRowSpan(b, 3);

            b.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(1);
            b.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

            // Then add your border to the grid
            g.Children.Add(b);
```

But for the ContentPresneter I dont know how to do that